# Add a custom controller entry in the Sonata menu

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'm trying to following [this section](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu.html#add-a-custom-controller-entry-in-the-menu) on Sonata's official website to add a custom controller to my menu.

What I have is a working controller;

```
class HelloController extends Controller {

    /**
     * 
     * @Template()
     * @param type $name
     * @return type
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        $admin_pool = $this->get('sonata.admin.pool');

        return array(
            'admin_pool' => $admin_pool,
            'name' => $name
        );
    }
}
```

I have registered the controller as a service in my services.yml file;

```
app.hello_controller:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\HelloController
```

And finally I've added the controller route as an item to the menu;

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            Monitoring:
                items:
                    - app.hello_controller
```

But now I'm getting the error;

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Admin service "app.hello_controller" not found in admin pool.") in
>   SonataAdminBundle:Core:add_block.html.twig at line 5.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing, to add menu items this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your config. In you example you are adding an admin service with the service id `app.hello_controller` to the menu.

What you need to do is add the following config to add **one specific route / action** from the controller:

**config.yml**

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            Monitoring:
                items:
                    - route:     your_route_name
                      label:     Your Menu Item Label
```